# Parsing million words of list in python regular expression is slow

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working on a project in python which takes content from web links and find some important words from content of that page.
I used regular expression to do so.
But it takes huge time to get the results.

### How it works:

1. It makes request to given url
2. take whole html content and data from external js files(within src attribute of  tag)
3. Save those things to list. (name it as file, used in re later)
4. and then perform searching of important data using regular expression.

Here is the sample:

### List:

list = `['secret', 'secret_key', 'token', 'secret_token', 'auth_token','access_token','username','password','aws_access_key_id','aws_secret_access_key', 'secretkey']`

### Regular Expression:

```
for item in seclst:
    try:
        secregex = r'(["\']?[\w\-]*' + item + '[\w\-]*[\s]*["\']?[\s]*[:=>]{1,2}[\s]*["\'](.*?)["\'])'
        matches = re.finditer(secregex, file, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE )
        for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
            if len(match.group(2)) > 0:
                secretList.add(match.group())
    except:
        pass
```

There are some other functions too.

### Execution time and explanation:

1. When I use 'https://www.facebook.com'(without cookies) it takes approximately 41 seconds (including doing other functionalities)
2. When I use 'https://www.facebook.com'(with cookies) it takes approximately 5 to 6 min (including doing other functionalities)

How can I optimize it?

Comment: I find it implausible that any text analysis of a web page could take minutes. I think that there is something you haven't told us about what your code is doing.

Comment: You also tagged this question as [tag:multithreading], but there isn't any multithreading in this code. Voting to close this question as "Unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Also why are you looking for `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`? I hope this isn't for anything nefarious.

Comment: This project is for security purpose @BaileyParker .

Comment: @200_success I have used multi-threading in this, but it doesn't helped me for this purpose.

Comment: Please post the whole program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that might help is compiling into a single regex once before the loop:

```
p = re.compile(r'(["\']?[\w\-]*(?:' + '|'.join(seclst) + ')[\w\-]*[\s]*["\']?[\s]*[:=>]{1,2}[\s]*["\'](.*?)["\'])')
for item in seclst:
    try:
        matches = p.finditer(file, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE )
        for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
            if len(match.group(2)) > 0:
                secretList.add(match.group())
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: The time decreased to half. Thanks for that @solomon-ucko

Comment: @NeerajSonaniya Great! Glad I could help.